# Single client to multiple client support: multithreading conversion in java

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, client

So I don't know who to go about creating a multithreaded server. I have client and server working fine together but can't introduce multiple clients properly. Here is my Server code:

```
package dod;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import dod.game.GameLogic;

public class Server{
    Server(GameLogic game, int port) throws IOException{
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        Socket sock = null;
        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(4444);//port no.
            while(true){
                try{
                    sock = ss.accept();     
                    ClientThread thread = new ClientThread(game, sock);
                    System.out.println("Adding new player...");
                    thread.run();
                }catch(final Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception d){
            System.out.println(d);
        }finally{
            if(ss!=null){
                ss.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my thread class:

```
package dod;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import dod.game.GameLogic;
import dod.game.PlayerListener;

public class ClientThread extends CommandLineUser implements PlayerListener, Runnable{
    DataInputStream in;
    PrintStream out;

    // The game which the command line user will operate on.
    // This is private to enforce the use of "processCommand".
    ClientThread(GameLogic game, Socket sock) {
        super(game);
        try{
            in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
        game.addPlayer(this);
    }

    /**
     * Constantly asks the user for new commands
     */
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Added new human player.");
        // Keep listening forever
        while(true){
            try{
                // Try to grab a command from the command line
                final String command = in.readLine();;
                // Test for EOF (ctrl-D)
                if(command == null){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                processCommand(command);

            }catch(final RuntimeException e){
                System.err.println(e.toString());
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Outputs a message to the player
     * 
     * @param message
     *            the message to send to the player.
     */
    public void outputMessage(String message) {
        out.print(message);
    }

}
```

Not asking for new code as such, just need pointers as to what I need to do have multiple client connection at the same time! Thanks to anyone who helps out!

Comment: Are you asking about sending messages to other clients about new client connection?

Comment: `DataInputStream.readLine()` is a deprecated method. Do not use it.

Comment: You have to read about, How to start a Thread? You are calling run method directly. call start() that will call run() internally.

Comment: Yeah I want to process the data that the clients pass (in text form) and then return them the processed result. After that I want to be able to broadcast a message from the server but I expect that shouldn't be difficult to extend on a server with multiple clients.

Comment: what do i use instead of DataInputStream.readLine()? and yeah thats because i have changed the run method and so if i call start() then i get errors.

Comment: Where are you calling method `outputMessage`?

Comment: use new Thread(thread).start();

Comment: @Braj in the commandlineuser class that client thread inherits from.

Comment: @braj is that instead of `ClientThread thread = new ClientThread(game, sock);` or after?

Comment: How we know it. You have to share minimal runnable and tested code.

Comment: The method `readLine()` from the type [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

To start, add new Thread(clientThread) in the server and call start() on it - as is everything's happening on the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Server{
    Server(GameLogic game, int port) throws IOException{
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        Socket sock = null;
        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(4444);//port no.
            while(true){
                try{
                    sock = ss.accept();     
                    ClientThread thread = new ClientThread(game, sock);
                    System.out.println("Adding new player...");
                    thread.start(); //you have to use start instead of run method to create multi thread application.
                }catch(final Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception d){
            System.out.println(d);
        }finally{
            if(ss!=null){
                ss.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have to use start instead of run method to create multi thread application.

If you want to send messages about new connections you have to hold sock in a list and when a new connection accepted send message to all socket object in list. (server broadcasts to all connected sockets)

I hope it helps.

Comment: You are right. CommandLineUser may be extended from Thread? Not a clear example, I thought

Comment: okay I have a list that each time a socket is accept, the socket is added to an array list. how do i make sure that the correct response from process command is send back?

Comment: If I understood what you mean, this is the connected clients responsibility. They connected to your server and waiting for your response. So they must parse the message which server sent them.

Comment: so your saying that every response should be sent to every client and then the client should only print the one relevant? that sounds really inefficient.

Comment: No, socket holds connection between server and client. If server send any message to a client, client must be parse the message and make its own decision. But if any client want to send a message to anoher client . This situation is different. Server must take the message and send it to true client. Maybe you can use map instead of list to hold sockets with their identity.

Comment: yeah i don't want clients to be able to talk to other clients. in clientThread class am I supposed to refer to the specific client when processing the input command received?

Comment: You may be have a look "Observer design pattern". I did not understand what are you trying to do.